# QZ tray prints RAW print instead of Actual Barcode

Tags: zebra-printers, qz-tray

I am a trying to print Shipping labels from a website to my TSC DA310 thermal printer. I have installed QZ tray locally, but my printer is printer Raw commands instead of the shipping label along with the barcode etc. Anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: Do you know which raw commands are being sent?  For example, if they look like this `^XA ^FO ..`, they're ZPL.  Also, have you tried to setup the printer as a raw device to bypass the driver? https://qz.io/wiki/setting-up-a-raw-printer-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [DA310 user's manual](https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/DownloadFile/readpdf/support/277/DA210_user_manual_E.pdf#page=11), this printer has a special "TSPL-EZD" firmware which emulates
"out of the box" the following label formats:

- Eltron® EPL command emulation
- Zebra® ZPL command emulation
- Datamax® DPL command emulation

To quote the original symptom:

> my printer is printer Raw commands instead of the shipping label along with the barcode etc.

Since all shipping providers provide commands in one of the above formats, this suggests that the vendor-provided driver may be interfering with the printing.

- One way to bypass the driver is to change it from `TSC DA310` to `Generic / Text Only` using **Printer Properties, Advanced, New Driver**.
- Since this printer driver is provided by a 3rd party (at time of writing, a company called "Seagull Scientific") you may consider reaching out to Seagull Scientific with this particular problem.  At time of writing this, te default driver does not seem to offer any configurable options regarding specifically to language emulation.
- If all else fails, [reach out to TSC technical support](https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/support) to see how to send raw label commands to their hardware.

TSC technical support will want to know which label format you are sending.  To find out, see the following reference:

- ZPL usually looks like this: `^XA ^FO ...`
- EPL usually looks like this: `N q812 Q1218 B5 ... A310 ..`
- DPL usually looks like this: `<STX>L D11`

Lastly, for help using the TSC-series printers with QZ Tray (per `qz-tray` tag), you may reach out directly to [support](https://qz.io/support) or ask a new question and link it here in the comments.